# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

"В Крыму(,) кроме моря(,) есть много замечательных мест" - выделяется ли запятыми оборот "кроме моря"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оборот с предлогом *кроме* относится к обособленным дополнениям. Его обособление факультативно (на усмотрение автора). Обособление дополнений связано с их смысловой нагрузкой, степенью близости к основной части предложения, объемом конструкции, желанием говорящего или пишущего подчеркнуть их роль в предложении.

я бы обособила. В  середине предложения обороты с "кроме" чаще всего обособляются.